# Python import fails from directory in sys.path

Tags: python

I have two Python projects:

C:\Python_Projects\ValScripts

- `Random.py`

C:\Python_Projects\Valpylib

- `__init__.py`
- `read_functions.py`

I have added Valpylib to PYTHONPATH environment variable:
[image: Environment Variables]

This is the code I am trying to execute in ValScripts.Random.py:

```
import sys

for d in sys.path:
    print(d)
    
from Valpylib import read_functions as vf_read
```

Which produces the following result:

$ set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && "c:\Python_Projects\ValScripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u "c:\Python_Projects\ValScripts\Random.py"

c:\Python_Projects\ValScripts
C:\Python_Projects\Valpylib
C:\Users\mlax16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip
C:\Users\mlax16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs
C:\Users\mlax16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
C:\Users\mlax16\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Python_Projects\ValScripts\venv
C:\Python_Projects\ValScripts\venv\lib\site-packages

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python_Projects\ValScripts\Random.py", line 6, in 
from Valpylib import read_functions as vf_read
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Valpylib'

Why is 'Valpylib' module not recognized even though it exists in sys.path?

Comment: I think the syntax should be `from file import function` or `from file import *` if you want everything. If you don't want to flood your namespace you can just `import file` and then use `file.function` in the code to refer to functions in the imported file.

Comment: In your case "file" would be "read_file". I'm your code you're trying to import a folder rather than a file. So if you have a function `read()` in `read_file.py` you could say `from read_file import read`.

Comment: You may need to add the specific file that you want to import to the path as well